# prevent the hacker from creating a new customer account

Tags: magento2

How can I prevent the hacker from creating a new customer account
I tried to do Google CAPTCHA, but I have a problem with the theme and it does not appear.
my site in Amazon and I used cloud flare.
Is there another solution?
Very Thanks
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LWf4.png)

Answer (score 1):

There are several steps you can take to prevent hackers from creating new customer accounts on the frontend in Magento 2:

1. Use CAPTCHA on the registration form to prevent automated bots from
   creating new accounts.
2. Use security plugins like two-factor authentication, google
   reCAPTCHA, IP blocking, etc.
3. Limit the number of login attempts to prevent brute force attacks.
4. Use a web application firewall (WAF) to block malicious traffic to your site.
5. Keep your Magento installation and extensions up to date to ensure that all known vulnerabilities are patched.
6. If you are using cloudflare you can enable the threat management rule to protect your site from malicious traffic.
7. Regularly monitor your site's logs and be on the lookout for suspicious activity.
8. Make sure your hosting provider is also following best practices for security.
9. Use an email verification system for new accounts to ensure that the email address provided is valid.
10. Monitor IP addresses that are creating multiple accounts and block them if necessary.

*If you are still having trouble getting the CAPTCHA to appear on your theme, you may want to contact the theme developer for support or consider using a different theme that is known to be compatible with Magento 2.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I will try one of the methods you mentioned